# From my radiobutton on VF page I am not able to call the method on change when apex:selectRadio is inside the actionregion

Tags: visualforce, rerender, actionsupport, actionregion

From my apex:selectRadio on VF page I am not able to call the method on change when apex:selectRadio is inside the actionregion. I wan to call am method and also wan to display and hide a outputpanl when I select the apex:selectRadio. It do not work when I put the code inside the actionregion else I am getting an error on required field. Please help me my code :

```
<td class="leftColumn labelCol">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Audio" for="conferenceList" />
                    </td>
                    <td>


                        <apex:outputPanel id="SelectAudio">
                        <apex:actionRegion immediate="true">
                        <apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedCallOption}">
                           <apex:selectOptions value="{!CallOption}"/>
                           <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!checkConferenceValue}" reRender="pageError, builtinAudio, PrivateNumber" status="changeCallOption"/>   
                           <apex:actionStatus startText="Updating ..." id="changeCallOption" /> 
                        </apex:selectRadio>
                        </apex:actionRegion>

                        <apex:outputPanel id="builtinAudio" style="text-align: right;" >
                            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(selectedCallOption == 'bulit-in', True, false)}">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="voipCheck" value="{!VoIP_call}"/>
                                    </td><td>
                                    <apex:outputLabel value="VoIP - Requires microphone and speakers" for="voipCheck" Styleclass="leftColumn labelCol"></apex:outputLabel>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="Long_distance" value="{!Long_distance_call}"/>
                                    </td><td style="text-align: left;">
                                    <apex:outputLabel value="Long distance number" for="Long_distance" Styleclass="leftColumn labelCol"></apex:outputLabel>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:outputPanel>




                        <apex:outputPanel id="PrivateNumber" style="text-align: right;" >  
                            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(selectedCallOption == 'conference-call', True, false)}">
                                <table style="width:400px;">
                                <tr border="1"> 
                                    <td style="width:100%;">  
                                        <apex:outputLabel value="Private Number" for="privateNo" Styleclass="leftColumn labelCol"></apex:outputLabel>
                                     </td>
                                     <td style="width:100%;">
                                        <apex:inputTextarea id="privateNo" value="{!privateNumber}" style="width:260px;" />                                             
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td style="width:100%;">                                             
                                        <apex:outputLabel value="Mark as Permanent" for="makePermanent" Styleclass="leftColumn labelCol"></apex:outputLabel>
                                     </td>
                                     <td style="text-align: left; width:100%;">
                                        <apex:inputCheckbox id="makePermanent" value="{!makePermanent}"   /> 
                                     </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:outputPanel>


                      </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem you are encountering is because you are using `immediate=true`.

When you use this parameter, no data is posted to the server. This parameter is primarily meant for `cancel`-like activities, where no post-back of data would be required to complete the action.